# reactjs app: s3 bucket and nginx reverse proxy not working with sub path

Tags: reactjs, docker, amazon-s3, routes

I want to run the reactjs app on a subpath `/troubleshoot`

so i had the following configuration in the reactjs app

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "App";

// Material Dashboard 2 React Context Provider
import { MaterialUIControllerProvider } from "context";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter basename="/troubleshoot">
    <MaterialUIControllerProvider>
      <App />
    </MaterialUIControllerProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "2.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/troubleshoot",
```

I build the project and put it in s3 bucket

[image]

and now i trying to run in nginx using

```
server {
    listen 80;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/cogclient.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/cogclient.error.log;
    server_name localhost;

    location /troubleshoot/ {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        set $bucket_name test 
        set $bucket "$bucket_name.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
        proxy_pass "http://$bucket/";

        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $bucket;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_hide_header x-amz-id-2;
        proxy_hide_header x-amz-request-id;
    }

}
```

When i run the nginx server and try to access `localhost/troubleshoot`

i see a blank page

[image]

the reason is because of subpath is not working well in s3 bucket. we can see in the below image.

I was able to make this work with an nginx docker image

my docker file. I am putting the build in troubleshoot folder

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/html/troubleshoot
COPY ./build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/troubleshoot/
RUN ls -alR /usr/share/nginx/html
```

and my nginx conf

```
server {
  
  listen       80;
  
  location /troubleshoot {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /troubleshoot/index.html;
  }
}
```

and everything is working with the above docker docker setup.

what can be done, to make s3 bucket work same as the docker image works using subpath

[image]